# Result of git rebase is different from what is shown in the git documentation

Tags: git, powershell, version-control, git-rebase

Suppose I create a simple local repo following the example shown in the main [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description) for `git rebase`:

```
          A---B---C topic
         /
    D---E---F---G master
```

I'm on windows so I use Powershell to do this, included for convenience:

```
md first-example
cd first-example
git init

function Create-Commits
{
    param (
        $Commits,
        $Branch
    )

    foreach ($commit in $commits)
    {
        git checkout $Branch
        new-item "$commit.txt"
        git add "$commit.txt"
        git commit -m "$commit"
        git tag $commit
    }
}

Create-Commits -Commits @("D", "E") -Branch master

git branch topic

Create-Commits -Commits @("A") -Branch topic
Create-Commits @("F") -Branch master
Create-Commits -Commits @("B") -Branch topic
Create-Commits -Commits @("G") -Branch master
Create-Commits -Commits @("C") -Branch topic

git log --graph --format="%(describe:tags=true)" --all
cd ../
```

Now, according to the text in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description):

> Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "topic":
>
> ```
>           A---B---C topic
>         /
>    D---E---F---G master
> ```
>
> From this point, the result of either of the following commands:
>
> `git rebase master`
>
> `git rebase master topic`
>
> would be:
>
> ```
>                  A'--B'--C' topic
>                 /
>    D---E---F---G master
> ```

When I try this, Here's what I get for `git log --graph --format="%(describe:tags=true)" --all`:

```
* G-3-g57a4992
* G-2-gcb715a5
* G-1-g5334a53
* G
* F
| * C
| * B
| * A
|/  
* E
* D
```

Here's what I get for `git log --graph --format="%(describe:tags=true)" topic`

```
* G-3-g57a4992
* G-2-gcb715a5
* G-1-g5334a53
* G
* F
* E
* D
```

And here's what I get for `git log --graph --format="%(describe:tags=true)" master`

```
* G
* F
* E
* D
```

Aside from the fact that the resulting revision history is different from what is stated in the docs, the commits with tags `A`, `B` and `C` don't seem to belong to any branch.

What happened with those commits and why have they not been removed altogether as suggested by the documentation? Do they belong to any specific branch now?

Comment: The docs ignore those commits, but that doesn't mean they just disappear: A', B' and C' are _new commits_ with the same content; A, B and C will still be in the reflog even though they're no longer on the branch.

Comment: So they don't get deleted? How can I otherwise access them? Is there a way to rebase such that those commits disappear?

Comment: Well you _tagged_ them, you can still use that or their hash to check them out.

Comment: I did .... I guess I'm just confused as to why they're still there. Most documentation on `rebase` gives the impression that they are somehow removed...

Comment: The original commits are not removed.... they are _eventually_ GCed if they are not in the history of any relevant reference (branches, tags, stashes, reflogs).

Comment: what do you mean by "GCed"?

Comment: Garbage collected - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc. And no, the documentation doesn't say they're _removed_, but generally you don't care about the old versions and they're unreachable. Tagging a commit then rebasing it is probably a mistake, because the _old_ commit is still tagged.

Comment: Git does not really modify a commit or delete a commit. It creates a new commit to replace the original one.  If the original commit is just removed, what would users think when they want to restore it? You could use `git for-each-ref --contains C` or `git for-each-ref --points-at C` to find out the refs that reference to C. The output does not include stash entries.

Comment: @user32882 Has the answer helped in clearing up the confusion?

Comment: @knittl I'm going to say yes although I haven't really had the time to read your answer thoroughly. Might come back to it at some later point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The history still matches, the Git documentation only draws them on 2 parallel lines, your history shows them as a single line.

```
A-B-C-D
```

and

```
A-B
   \
    C-D
```

is exactly the same history.

As to why you still see your old commits: `git rebase` never *removes* commits, it only recreates/copies them and then sets the "branch" label to point to the new commits. The old commits are still in the Git object database (the `.git/objects` directory).

`git log` starts at *refs* (branches or tags) and will display all commits *reachable* through those refs; starting at the commit pointed to by the ref, then walking the `parent:` pointers of each commit.

You are running `git tag $commit` for every commit, so they remain reachable, even after creating copies of them and moving the original branch pointer.